# Print Matrix in python with specific formatting

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to print a matrix like the following using python:

[image]

Can anyone help me to write the code?
See the format is different with respect to the default format of python.

Comment: SO is not a code writing platform, please make an effort yourselves and if you then run into problems, then only ask a question and that also after researching your problem on the internet.

Comment: Please never post a screenshot, always try to copy/paste the code or output.

Comment: for i in range (150):
 print("%10i" %(i)), 

I am not very good with coding. 
I am able to write this much.
but that does not giving the the desired output.

Comment: @UbdusSamad 
I tried to paste the ouput but the format is changed after pasting. 
So to be precise about the problem I post the screenshot.

Comment: So you want a matrix of 10x15? Are you willing to use numpy, or a standard array of arrays will do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
x=[str(i) for i in range(1,151)]

t=[x[i:i+15] for i in range(0,136,15)]

for i in range(len(t)):
    for j in range(len(t[i])):
        if(len(t[i][j])==1):
            t[i][j]='   '+t[i][j]
        elif(len(t[i][j])==2):
            t[i][j]='  '+t[i][j]
        elif(len(t[i][j])==3):
            t[i][j]=' '+t[i][j]

for x in t:
    string=''.join(x)
    print(string)

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45
  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75
  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105
 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135
 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below requires only one for-loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(''.join(map(lambda x:' '*(5-len(str(x)))+str(x),range(i*15+1,(i+1)*15+1))))
```

It prints out:

```
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30
   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45
   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59   60
   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72   73   74   75
   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90
   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100  101  102  103  104  105
  106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119  120
  121  122  123  124  125  126  127  128  129  130  131  132  133  134  135
  136  137  138  139  140  141  142  143  144  145  146  147  148  149  150
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who tried to give the solution to this answer. 
I somehow able to write my own code,

```
atomnumber=22284

        for j in range(int(atomnumber/10)):

                print('{0:6d} {1:7d} {2:8d} {3:9d} {4:10d} {5:11d} {6:12d} {7:13d} {8:14d} {9:15d}'\
    .format(10*j+1, 10*j+2, 10*j+3, 10*j+4, 10*j+5,10*j+6,\
     10*j+7, 10*j+8, 10*j+9, 10*j+10))

        if (atomnumber%10) !=0 :
            a=(atomnumber%10)
            b=atomnumber
            if (atomnumber%10)==1 :
                print ('{0:6d} '.format((b-a)+1,))
            if (atomnumber%10)==2 :
                print ('{0:6d} {1:7d} '.format((b-a)+1,(b-a)+2,))
            if (atomnumber%10)==3 :
                print ('{0:6d} {1:7d} {2:8d} '.format((b-a)+1,(b-a)+2,(b-a)+3,))
            if (atomnumber%10)==4 :
                print ('{0:6d} {1:7d} {2:8d} {3:9d} \
                '.format((b-a)+1,(b-a)+2,(b-a)+3,(b-a)+4,))
            if (atomnumber%10)==5 :
                print ('{0:6d} {1:7d} {2:8d} {3:9d} {4:10d} \
                '.format((b-a)+1,(b-a)+2,(b-a)+3,(b-a)+4,(b-a)+5,))
            if (atomnumber%10)==6 :
                print ('{0:6d} {1:7d} {2:8d} {3:9d} {4:10d} {5:11d}\
                '.format((b-a)+1,(b-a)+2,(b-a)+3,(b-a)+4,(b-a)+5,(b-a)+6,))
            if (atomnumber%10)==7 :
                print ('{0:6d} {1:7d} {2:8d} {3:9d} {4:10d} {5:11d} {6:12d} \
                '.format((b-a)+1,(b-a)+2,(b-a)+3,(b-a)+4,(b-a)+5,(b-a)+6,(b-a)+7,))
            if (atomnumber%10)==8 :
                print ('{0:6d} {1:7d} {2:8d} {3:9d} {4:10d} {5:11d} {6:12d} {7:13d} \
                '.format((b-a)+1,(b-a)+2,(b-a)+3,(b-a)+4,(b-a)+5,(b-a)+6,(b-a)+7,(b-a)+8,))
            if (atomnumber%10)==9 :
                print ('{0:6d} {1:7d} {2:8d} {3:9d} {4:10d} {5:11d} {6:12d} {7:13d} {8:14d} \
                '.format((b-a)+1,(b-a)+2,(b-a)+3,(b-a)+4,(b-a)+5,(b-a)+6,(b-a)+7,(b-a)+8,(b-a)+9,))
```